# What does δ (lowercase delta) represent in probability (mutually exclusive propositions)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reading through Jayne's *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science* and he mentions that given a set of propositions {$A_1A_2...A_n$} that are mutually exclusive given information $B$ (meaning, any two of them can't be true simultaneously given $B$), they can be expressed as

$$p(A_iA_j|B) = p(A_i|B)\delta_{ij}$$

What is the $\delta_{ij}$?

I would think that the probability $p(A_iA_j|B) =0$ so I'm not sure what the point of the right-hand side even is.

Comment: $p(A_iA_j|B)$  need not be $0$ when $i=j$ i.e. when $A_i$ and $A_j$ are the same event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)". The value of $\delta_{ij}$ is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

It's not specific to probability theory.

In your example you are right to say that the right hand side is $0$ - except when $i=j$.